# Django model structure - best practice

Tags: django, model, structure, relational-database

For a little free fruit site, I have the following model relationship:

3 classes - Apples, Strawberries, and Locations

Apples and Strawberries list all "properties" of the fruits:

```
class Apple(models.Model):     
    treeSize = ...
    age = ...

class Strawberry(models.Model):
    fieldArea = ...
```

Now I want to record all locations with the fruits. So far I have a class with locations and attributes for Apples and Strawberries, which keeps the ForeignKeys to the kind of fruits. But that can't be it. **It looks very inefficient, esp. if I add multiple other fruit types.** Also, I would need to check that each location has at least one of the fruit keys.

```
class Location(models.Model):    
     lat = ...
     lng = ... 
     appleType = models.ForeignKey(Apple, null = True)
     strawberryType = models.ForeignKey(Strawberry, null = True)
```

**Is there a better way to design the relationships or the model structure?**
What would be the best practice for this problem?

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: This is where the relation between "ORM" and "OODB" begins to break down.

Comment: Hi Ignacio, 

Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case where you need to use the [Generic Relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Instead of storing the Foreign Key to each one of those, you store the content type id (that recognizes Strawberries from Apples) and the object ids. You can of-course, develop this with your own conventions using the relevant strings within the `Location` model, but all that hard work is done for you in the django's built in [Content Type Framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).